# MySQL auto truncation not working with c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, c3p0

I have a table.

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

... returns empty.

```
mysql> create table testtable ( name varbinary(5));

mysql> insert into testtable values('hellowhowareyoudsafafas');

Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Data gets inserted into the table. But if i use c3p0's `ComboPoolDataSource`, I get the exception `com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation`.

Since I had not set the MySQL strict mode on MySQL 5.1, I was expecting the data to get stored in the table. What should I do to allow auto truncation via c3p0.

=====ok i did it , but is there a neater way======

```
PreparedStatement ps1 =  connection.prepareStatement("SELECT @@sql_mode");
    ResultSet rs = ps1.executeQuery();
    String originalSqlMode = "";
    if(rs.next()) {
        originalSqlMode = rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println(originalSqlMode);
    }
    String newSqlMode = originalSqlMode.replace("STRICT_ALL_TABLES", "").replace("STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", "").replace(",,", ",");
    ps1 = connection.prepareStatement("SET SESSION sql_mode=?");
    ps1.setString(1, newSqlMode);
    ps1.execute();
    PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into testtable values (?)");
    ps2.setString(1, "indianpeople");
    ps2.execute();
```

Comment: Here's a little thought of mine, until you get a proper answer... Even in MySQL you get a warning. I think that catching `MysqlDataTruncation` would be the Java equivalent of ignoring the warning.

Answer (score 0):

so, probably the simplest solution, if you control the database, is to execute MySQL in the mode you want using the --sql-mode switch on mysqld. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html

if that's not an option, you can use your mode-altering code in a c3p0 ConnectionCustomizer. It looks like "session" is defined as the lifetime of the Connection, so you should be able to just override the onAcquire method of AbstractConnectionCustomizer. the option will then be set just once, when the Connection is acquired from the database. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers

good luck!